# What is the meaning of min_distance and min_angle in hough_line_peaks()?

Tags: scikit-image

Can someone explain min_distance and min_angle optional parameters, please ?

http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.hough_line_peaks

For min_angle=n, I thought it would check if the next angle's line was minimum superior to n element in my theta array for being accepted.

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.transform import hough_line,hough_line_peaks

iden = np.identity(200)
hspace, angles, dists = hough_line(iden,theta=np.linspace(-np.pi/2,np.pi/2,1800)) # 0.1 degree resolution
hspace, angles, dists = hough_line_peaks(hspace, angles, dists,min_distance=0,min_angle=20) # 2 degree minimum before accepting as new line?  
print(hspace, angles*180/np.pi, dists)
```

output : [200 126 124] [-44.9749861  -45.27515286 -44.67481934] [ 0.50088496 -0.50088496  1.50265487]

The angle array shows that i'm getting wrong with this. The parameter accepts only integer, i'm not sure of what it could be ...

Comment: Issue filed at https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/2765 for further investigation.

Comment: @StefanvanderWalt I don't think there is an issue with the behavior of the function. Please check my answer and give me some feedback if you think I'm wrong. If you agree with me, the filled issue should be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong with the function `hough_line_peaks()` itself.

`min_angle` and `min_distance` define a zone around an already found peak, in which no other peak can be found (i.e., you consider that a peak that close from another peak is actually a single unique peak)

In the accumulator of the Hough transform, the 2 dimensions are: angles and distances. You basically set by an integer the number of bins in the accumulator that have to be ignored around an already found peak.

By setting `min_distance` to 0, you are only avoiding to get 2 peaks that have the exact same distance parameter AND an angle parameter difference less than `20 * angle_resolution ~= 20 * 0.1 = .2`. None of the 3 peaks that are returned have the same distance parameter and therefore, the condition you set is respected.

Also, be aware that your angle resolution is not exactly `0.1` degrees unless the third parameter in `np.linspace` is `1801`. This is the way `np.linspace` behaves, you give it the total number of points. `hough_line_peaks` just takes the returned vector as an input argument. You could also use `np.arange` which allows you to pass the `step` as an argument.

**Edit**

The angle array returned is in *degrees ?!?*. I would expect radians as for the input... The values should correspond to some of the values of `np.linspace(-np.pi/2, np.pi/2, 1800)`.

**End of edit**

Basically, it works this way:

- Find the highest value in accumulator -> `200, -44.9749861, 0.50088496` (`200` means that 200 pixels have been assigned to this bin of the accumulator)
- Set the bins of the accumulator that are around the peak bin `[bin - min_dist: bin + min_dist, bin - min_angle:bin + min_angle]` to `0`
- Find the second biggest value in the accumulator and so on.

**Edit 2:**

Why the results `accumulator_value = [200 126 124]`, `angle_params = [a b c]` and `dist_params = [d e f]` (for all `d`, `e`, `f` such as `d != e` and `e != f`) are not incoherent with the parameters `min_angle = X` and `min_distance = 0`

The strongest peak in the accumulator is found at the bin`angle_param = a` and `dist_param = d`.

The search for the second peak will be carried out by discarding this bin in the accumulator as well as the bins that are located at a number of bins `<= X` (side note: it is possible that it is `X/2` but this does not change the reasoning here) on the angle "direction" and at a number of bins `<= 0` on the distance "direction" from the "peak's" bin.

Only this. So, the other peaks found in your case are located in a bin whose distance parameter is different that any other peak found. Therefore there is no reason for discarding them.

The accumulator is simply a 2-dimensional table of bins, one direction representing the angles and the other the distances.

Comment: Thank you; I think your analysis is spot-on.  I think we should update the docs to make this clearer (if you want to help with that, it would be greatly appreciated).

Comment: I would be more than happy to help clarifying the documentation as I worked quite a bit with these functions. I just don't know how to proceed for helping. Maybe give me the instructions in a chat as you seem to be familiar with this :)

Comment: @guih I would like to keep this question self-contained. Raise your doubts here. Indeed, I thought the returned values where wrongly ordered... It seems that the angles are returned in degrees though the input has to be in radians...

Comment: Yes, the angles are returned in radians. But there is something i can't get. Why using min_angles=50 (my answer on github) is not discarding the two other peaks ?

Comment: @guih Your returned parameters are in this order no? `hspace, angles, dists`, so I guess the angles parameters are ` [-44.9749861 -45.27515286 -44.67481934]` and the distances parameters are `[ 0.50088496 -0.50088496 1.50265487]` (from the way you wrote the question). Intuitively I would have thought it is the opposite. Can you confirm this point? You still misunderstand the way `min_angle` and `min_dist` work. I will edit my answer later to further clarify.

Comment: Yes it is returned in this order.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations ... but i have to insist with min_angles = 70 ,min_dists = 0,  theta = 0.1 degree i still have as output [200 132 132] [-45.  -44.7 -45.3] [ 0.50088496  1.50265487 -0.50088496]. It should discard values on angles axis, shoudnt it ? It should only keep the strongest peak ?

Comment: No, BOTH parameters define a 2-dimensional window around the previously found peak(s). Inside this window, no new peak can be found. Here your window is a vector. It only prevent some peaks having the EXACT same distance parameter AND an angle parameter different from less than 70 * resolution_angle from being detected as a new peak. It is an AND relationship not an OR relationship.

Comment: I got it :) ! Many thanks for your time and explanations !!